# Difference in Hamiltonian when using conjugate momenta vs. Velocity

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, velocity, hamiltonian-formalism

I was recently reading through David Tong's "Application of Quantum Mechanics" (found [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm/aqm.pdf)) and in it he talks about the completely classical example of a charged particle in a magnetic field (page 4). The Lagrangian for such a system is given by:
$$L = \frac{1}{2}m\mathbf{\dot{x}}^2+q\mathbf{\dot{x}}\cdot\mathbf{A}-q\phi$$
and when changing to the Hamiltonian formulation, we use the canonical momentum ($\mathbf{p}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{\dot{x}}}$) and get:
$$H=\mathbf{\dot{x}}\cdot\mathbf{p}-L=\frac{1}{2m}(\mathbf{p}-q\mathbf{A})^2+q\phi$$
This is fine. He then goes on to say, however, "Written in terms of the velocity of the particle, the Hamiltonian looks the same as it would in the absence of a magnetic field: $H=\frac{1}{2}m\mathbf{\dot{x}}^2+q\phi$. This is the statement that a magnetic field does no work and so doesn't change the energy of the system." What exactly is he doing here – meaning, can one freely choose to express the Hamiltonian in terms of either the velocity *or* the conjugate momentum? I have never seen this done before, and am wondering if it has the same interpretation or if it changes things?

Additionally, the Hamiltonian was taught to me as having the interpretation that it represented the total energy of the system, and in this instance, the magnetic field should not do any work on the charge and therefore should not affect the overall energy of the system, so why then do we get a term in that is dependent on $\mathbf{A}$ when using the conjugate momentum? Looking for any pertinent discussion on either question.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the lagrangian $L$, the conjugate momentum is defined as:
$$
{\bf p} = \frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{ {\bf \dot x}}} = m {\bf \dot x}+q {\bf  A}.
$$
Therefore, the dependence on ${\bf A}$ in the last expression for the Hamiltonian exactly cancels the corresponding term in the definition of momentum to leave an expression for the kinetic energy independent on the vector potential.

As far as the first part of the question, strictly speaking the Hamiltonian is the function of the conjugate momenum. Due to the one-to-one correspondence between ${\bf \dot x}$ and ${\bf p}$, nothing prevents to change variable introducing a function $ H({\bf p}({\bf \dot x,{\bf x } }), {\bf  x })$

Comment: The dependence on $\mathbf{A}$ does cancel exactly when expressing the Hamiltonian in terms of the velocity, but not when expressing it in terms of the conjugate momentum. I guess the answer is that the canonical momentum is not gauge invariant, while the velocity is, hence why the $\mathbf{A}$ dependence drops out in the 1st case but not necessarily in the 2nd.

Comment: @Schoppe That's exactly my point. The kinetic energy has a unique expression in terms of velocity. For a charge in the presence of a vector potential, velocity is not simply proportional to the momentum but there is an additive vector potential term. Therefore, tha Hamiltonian as a function of $p$ contains an explicit dependence on $A$. Nevertheless, the final total energy does not depend on $A$ . Notice that such result is not directly related to gauge invariance.